# How do I tell a screen reader that a link is disabled?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I have a page with **n** sections. The sections are hidden and can only be shown by clicking their respective links.

On page load, only the first link is active and the rest n-1 links are `href="#"`. Based on some logic, the other links are activated individually. How do I make a screen reader understand that the link is **disabled** or **deactivated**?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is the [aria-disabled attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-disabled).

Comment: It is ambiguous that "and the rest n-1 links are disabled". Disabled how? Anyway, if they have a disabled attribute, check for that; if they are not displayed (CSS display: none), check for that, etc.

Comment: So then what's wrong with checking for the href's value in order to determine whether the link is disabled? Just follow your logic.

Comment: This sounds like a tab navigation. I'd suggest checking [the tab panel accessibility example on the OpenAjax website](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/34/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you would want screen readers to know that they are there, just disabled, I would use a button or link like so:

```
<button disabled>Section name</button>

<a href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Section name</a>
```

That would be good for a set of show/hide areas that are controlled by some external logic.

Once enabled, you should also consider some attributes to let people know how it works:

```
<a href="#" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Section name</a>
<div aria-expanded="false">Content to show</div>
```

When selected:

```
<a href="#" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Section name</a>
<div aria-expanded="true">Content to show</div>
```

On the other hand, if it is an accordion (one at a time) then I would use the accordion here:
http://whatsock.com/tsg/

You might not want to take on that framework, but just read the notes for accordions to understand it better.

Comment: I am actually using AccDc for the page. The page consists of links that behave like tabs.

Comment: That's a great start then. Have you tried using aria-disabled=true?

Comment: Yes I have. NVDA on firefox does not explicitly speak that its disabled

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: I changed the implementation to use buttons instead of the link. So disabling the button solved my issue. Your answer helped me understand the `aria-pressed` and `aria-disabled` so I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Bryan (creator of AccDc) mentioned: I had missed that the link needs a role of button (or to be a button) for aria-pressed to work. aria-disabled should work with links, but perhaps NVDA only supports it on buttons? A button should work, as should a link with role button.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI, the use of `aria-disabled` works best for elements that have a defined role, such as `role=button`.

So, if using an A tag with an `href` attribute, you can use `role=button` and `aria-disabled=true` and it will be announced correctly. I recommend using `tabindex="-1"` to remove it from the tab order as well to follow the standard behavior of a disabled active element.

E.G

`<a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true"> Label </a>`

Also, when using `aria-pressed`, you must also include `role=button`, otherwise it will not work correctly since this defines an ARIA Toggle control.

Comment: Works best: The highest number of assistive technology + browsers that support this approach